# Rigorous definition of $\lim\limits_{{\mathbf{|x|}\to\infty}}\mathbf{f(x)}=\infty$ $\mathbf{f}:M\to\mathbb{R^m}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence

I was asked to give a precise defintion

> $\lim\limits_{{\mathbf{|x|}\to\infty}}\mathbf{f(x)}=\infty$ with $\mathbf{f}:M\to\mathbb{R^m}$ and $M\subseteq\mathbb{R^n}$

I know for $$\lim\limits_{{x\to\infty}}f(x)=\infty$$ we would have: $\forall\epsilon >0,\exists$ $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)>\epsilon$ $\forall $ |x|>$\delta$.

I already know the precise definition of the expression $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ where $f$ is a scalar function on $\mathbf{R}$. But I want to know how this definition can be *generalized* to $\displaystyle \lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ where $f:M\to\mathbf{R}^m$ is a vector-valued function and $M$ is a subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$.

Also is there a difference between $f(\mathbf{x})$ and $\mathbf{f(x)}$, because my teacher often switches between these two.

Is there anyone who could help me out? I would be very grateful.

Comment: "I am unsure how the definition of ..." **Where** do you see this notation?

Comment: Likely you mean $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty} |f(x)| = \infty$.  Rather than $\rightarrow\infty$. Once the limit is taken (assuming it exists) it "equals" something, it does not go to something.

Comment: @user1046533 $\mathbf{f(x)}$ was not defined by our teacher. But in our script we have $f: M\to\mathbb{R^m}$

Comment: @Analysis_Mark: Does your teacher use any textbook? Or do they simply use their notes? What course are you taking?

Comment: Most  likely the bold face means "vector" in the sense of the first comment by user104.

Comment: Again, it is not hard to *guess* what the notation means. But in order to give a satisfying "rigorous" definition and thus a helpful answer for you and the readers, can you please provide the context of this notation? *Where* do you see this?

Comment: @user1046533 I don't quite understand. Last year we got this task: Give a rigorous definition of $\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. I already wrote the solution that was given to us. We probably have a different understanding of rigorous in my language. The only thing I wanted to know if I could use this solution and write $\mathbf{f(x)}$ and $|\mathbf{x}|$  instead of $|x|$ and $f(x)$ in this context

Comment: @user1046533 Yeah we always worked with $f: M\to\mathbb{R^m}$

Comment: @Analysis_Mark: What is $M$? A subset of what?

Comment: If that is the case, can you please edit your post more accurately? You may write the exercise statement clearly as "I was asked to give a precise definition of the expression $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$..." and separate whatever thoughts you have.

Comment: @user1046533 M is the subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: According to your comments, what you really want to ask is this: you already know the precise definition of the expression $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ where $f$ is a scalar function on $\mathbf{R}$. And you really want to know how your definition can be *generalized* to $\displaystyle \lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ where $f:M\to\mathbf{R}^m$ is a vector-valued function and $M$ is a subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$. Correct? Can you confirm?

Comment: Exactly. I am sorry if this was unclear but my english skills aren't that good.

Comment: You want to double-check your exercise. If $M$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$, then the limit expression does not make sense since you cannot have "$|x|\to\infty$".

Comment: @user1046533 Well yeah I am sorry our teacher gave us the task like this: Give the rigorous definitions of the following statements.... and then $\mathbf{f(x)}$ to infinity for $\mathbf{|x|}$ to infinity and so on. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:M\to\mathbf{R}^m$ be a function from a subset $M$ of $\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{R}^m$.

When $M$ is a *bounded* subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$, the expression $\displaystyle \lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)$ does not make sense because one cannot have "$|x|\to\infty$" for $x\in M$.

Simply assume that $M=\mathbf{R}^n$. Then one can define $\displaystyle \lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ as follows:

**Definition 1.** For every $M>0$, there exists $C>0$ such that $|f(x)|>M$ whenever $|x|>C$. Here $|\cdot|$ denotes the standard Euclidean norm in the corresponding space.

---

When $m>1$, people may use the notation $\mathbf{f}$ to emphasize that $\mathbf{f}$ is a *vector*-valued function where the codomain $\mathbf{R}^m$ is of more than dimension one.

Similarly, when $n>1$, $\mathbf{x}$ is used to emphasize the dimension of the domain.

If both $m,n>1$, the boldface $\mathbf{f(x)}$ is used rather than $f(x)$.

---

One can define anything "rigorously" as one wishes. Definitions *themselves* are not interesting/useful. What matters is what the definition allows one to *do*.

One way one may apply Definition 1, is to unify some corner cases of a statement regarding limits.

Comment: In this task, my teacher  wrote at one point $\mathbf{f(x)}$$\to\mathbf{y}$ for $|\mathbf{x}|\to\infty$ and the other 4 times he wrote something like $f(\mathbf{x})\to\infty$ for $|\mathbf{x}|\to\infty$. But I guess there is no difference right... I mean with regard to the f....he probably mistyped...

Comment: @Analysis_Mark: As long as you clearly know what the domain and the codomain for the function are, you would have no problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim\limits_{{\mathbf{|x|}\to\infty}}\mathbf{f(x)}\to\infty
$$
means
For every $A  > 0$, there exists $B > 0$ so that:
for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb R^n$, if
$|\mathbf{x}| > B$, then $|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})|>A$.

I'm guessing $\mathbf{f} : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ and
"$\infty$" on the right means the
extra point for the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: Sometimes "guessing" at the meaning of notation would be expeditious, but the OP has been responding to requests for clarification.  Perhaps in this case it is better to give them time to clear things up?